# How to convert dictionary of dictionary list value to python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Example my dictionary as below:

{{"Test1":{"a":[1],"b":[2],"c":[12345],"d":[7],"e":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]},

{"Test2":{"a":[2],"b":[2],"c":[55555],"d":[8],"e":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]},

{"Test3":{"a":[3],"b":[2],"c":[66665],"d":[5],"e":[1,2,3,4,5]},

{"Test1":{"a":[1],"b":[2],"c":[12345],"d":[7],"e":[11,12,13,14,15,16,17]},

{"Test2":{"a":[2],"b":[2],"c":[55555],"d":[8],"e":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]},

{"Test3":{"a":[3],"b":[2],"c":[66665],"d":[5],"e":[1,2,3,4,5]}
...
}
Some 50000 values  are .(Test1,Test2,Test3 with unique value repeated)

I need dataFrame Test 1 with columns as below and the row value should append from respective key.

Index    a   b   c           d   x    y   z     m    n    o    p

```
 0         1  2 12345    7    1   2   3     4     5   6    7

 1          1  2 12345   7     11 12 13 14   15 16 17
```

Some 50,000 rows

Similarly I need dataFrame for other variables.Test2,Test3,etc..

Please help